# Receiving "UnpicklingError: Invalid load key, 'v'." when trying to run truecase in Python

Tags: python, nltk, pickle

I'm trying to run a short snippet of code that uses the truecase Python package (it's used to restore capitalization in text), and I'm receiving an `UnpicklingError` because it loads a tokenizer from nltk.

I can't use `nltk.download` to install the missing nltk files because of server restrictions on my network, so I've downloaded the nltk_data directory directly onto my computer.  It looks like it's able to locate the file but it's having troubling opening the language pickle file.

```
import truecase
truecase.get_true_case('hey, what is the weather in new york?')

In [4]: runfile('/Users/{me}/Downloads/truecase-0.0.4/testingtruecase.py', wdir='/Users/{me}/Downloads/truecase-0.0.4')
Reloaded modules: truecase, truecase.TrueCaser
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-82ea1175dde8>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/{me}/Downloads/truecase-0.0.4/testingtruecase.py', wdir='/Users/{me}/Downloads/truecase-0.0.4')

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/{me}/Downloads/truecase-0.0.4/testingtruecase.py", line 10, in <module>
    truecase.get_true_case('hey, what is the weather in new york?')

  File "/Users/y99b/Downloads/truecase-0.0.4/truecase/__init__.py", line 7, in get_true_case
    return caser.get_true_case(sentence, out_of_vocabulary_token_option=out_of_vocabulary_token_option)

  File "/Users/{me}/Downloads/truecase-0.0.4/truecase/TrueCaser.py", line 80, in get_true_case
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 143, in word_tokenize
    sentences = [text] if preserve_line else sent_tokenize(text, language)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 104, in sent_tokenize
    tokenizer = load('tokenizers/punkt/{0}.pickle'.format(language))

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 873, in load
    resource_val = pickle.load(opened_resource)

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'v'.
```

Comment: Perhaps you need git lfs - https://git-lfs.github.com ?

Answer (score 4):

Found the issue, the pickle file I was working with was invalid and didn't actually have the right data in it (it just had a link to a github in the actual file).  I found a different download with the correct english.pickle file and everything works just fine.  If anyone has an invalid key 'v' error, it is likely to do with your actual pickle file.

Comment: had the same problem. I was storing file using git LFS when someone do git pull it's just rendering ref link not the actual file and your answer is helpful to find out that cause thanks, man... to pull large files needs to do `git lfs get` [source](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/325#issuecomment-104673499)

Answer (score 3):

The error in loading pickles is due to missing complete files. Due to their size, they are stored in a special section of the GIT and must be downloaded in a special way.

Using git lfs should help you solve the problem.

https://git-lfs.github.com/

```
> git lfs install
> git lfs fetch
> git lfs pull
```

Download git lfs, install it and try to pull the repo again using the commands above. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

your pickled file might be corrupted. Replace it with new file. It worked for me.